# Laravel4 - A view that hide some functionality when entering as guest

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to customize a single view that when the user is logged in, It will show `Edit` and  `Delete` buttons.

When the user is a guest, Those two buttons are going to be hidden.

I'm trying to use the same controllers and view files. And do the `Auth::check()` inside the views before every admin-only item.

Also i've added `auth` filter in all of the `Admin` routes.

The problem is when i access `/` without being logged it. It works as expected and hides the admin-only items. When accessing it as an admin it shows the admin-only items.

But when i click `Details` anchor tag. I get redirected to `/login` route as i'm trying to access an admin only route. I just want it to hide the admin-only items !

I've tried to type it manually to reach the details page : `/17` it gets me details about post with id equals to `17`. But when i click this tag it tries to redirects me to `/admin/post/list/17`. How to manage these redirection based on if i'm an admin or not ?

**EDIT**: I've deleted unrelated code.

Here's my routes :

```
<?php    
Route::get('login',                     array('before' => 'guest' , 'as' => 'getLogin',     'uses' => 'UserController@getLogin'));
Route::post('login',                    array('before' => 'csrf' ,  'as' => 'postLogin',    'uses' => 'UserController@postLogin'));
Route::get('make/me/an/admin/account',  array(                      'as' => 'getSignup',    'uses' => 'UserController@getCreateAdmin'));
Route::post('make/me/an/admin/account', array('before' => 'csrf',   'as' => 'postSignup',   'uses' => 'UserController@postCreateAdmin'));
Route::get('logout',                    array('before' => 'auth',   'as' => 'getLogout',    'uses' => 'UserController@getLogout'));

Route::group(array( 'before' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'admin'), function(){
    Route::get('/' , function(){
        return View::make('admin.main')->with('title', 'Main');
    });

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'post',), function(){
        Route::get('/',                 array('as' => 'listAllPosts',   'uses' => "PostController@listPosts"));
        Route::get('list',              array('as' => 'listAllPosts',   'uses' => "PostController@listPosts"));
        Route::get('list/{id}',         array('as' => 'listSinglePost', 'uses' => "PostController@showPost"));
            Route::post('addcomment/{post_id}',         array('as' => 'addComment',     'uses' => 'CommentController@addComment')); 
        });

    });
});

Route::get('/', array('as' => 'listAllPostsGuest', 'uses' => 'PostController@listPosts'));
Route::get('/{id}', array('as' => 'listSinglePostsGuest', 'uses' => 'PostController@showPost'));
```

The views that i tried to achieve what i talked about :

`list.blade.php` (Where is the details link that redirects me to `login` (inside the foreach) ):

```
@extends('layout.layout')

@section('header')

@stop

@section('content')

@if(Auth::check())
    <h2>Main - Admin - Post Main menu</h2>
@else 
    <h2>Main - Posts</h2>
@endif

@if(Auth::check())
    <ul>
        <li>{{ link_to_route('getAddPost', 'Add') }}</li>
    </ul>
@endif

@if(isset($message))
    <p>{{ $message }}</p>
@endif

@if(isset($posts))  
    <ul>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <li>
        <span>{{ $post->body }} - {{ count($post->comments) }} Comment(s)</span>
        @if(Auth::check())
            {{ Form::open(array('action' => array('PostController@deletePost', $post->id))) }}
                 {{ Form::submit('delete') }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
        @endif
        {{ link_to_route('PostController@showPost', 'Details', array("id" => $post->id)) }} 
    </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif

@if(Auth::check())
    {{ link_to('admin/', 'Back') }}
@else 
    {{ link_to('/', 'Back') }}
@endif

@stop
```

And here's my Controllers :

```
<?php

class PostController extends BaseController {

    public function listPosts(){
        $posts = Post::all();
        return View::make('admin.post.list')->with('posts' , $posts);
    }

    public function showPost($id){
        if(!is_numeric(trim($id))){
            return Redirect::action('PostController@listPosts');
        }

        $post = Post::find($id);

        if(empty($post)){
            return Redirect::action('PostController@listPosts');
        }
        return View::make('admin.post.postdetails')->with('post', $post);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using URLs prefixed with `admin` when they will be publicly facing as well? Also, I don't understand the second part about the `/17` URL redirecting to the admin post. I will say, though, that your Auth filter will fire before every URI that starts with `admin/`, so if you don't want things to redirect based on login status, I'd start there.

Comment: @Cryode Great. I've removed the prefixing for `admin` and `post` and did a couple of changes and it worked fine. Please post it as an answer to i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every URI that begins with `admin/` will have the `auth` filter run prior to any controller code loading. If your auth filter does any redirects, that's where the issue lies.

I'd recommend really figuring out how your URI structure is going to be set up (having public-facing URIs that start with `admin` doesn't make much sense). After that, you can set up your routes more efficiently and with less filter conflicts and such.